# Why is my resource getting blocked even though I allowed it specifically in the CSP declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, content-security-policy

Hi all hoping you can help but I don't know if you can. Having checked other questions about the CSP blocking, they all recommend to specifically allow your resource in the headers (or if you're using helmet, in a CSP declaration object) and now that I've now done that I still relentlessly get the same issue.

Here is my declaration via Helmet

```
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: [
        "'self'",
        'https://*.mapbox.com',
        'https://*.stripe.com',
        'blob',
      ],
      baseUri: ["'self'"],
      fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.cloudflare.com'],
      imgSrc: ["'self'", 'https://www.gstatic.com'],
      scriptSrc: [
        "'self'",
        'https://*.stripe.com',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
        'https://api.mapbox.com',
        'https://js.stripe.com',
        'blob',
      ],
      frameSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.stripe.com'],
      objectSrc: ["'none'"],
      styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
      upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
    },
  })
);
```

And then these are the errors:

```
web_worker.js:9 Refused to create a worker from 'blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/a115d817-1a59-46c1-97e5-355513ade597' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://*.stripe.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://api.mapbox.com https://js.stripe.com blob". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Another one here:

```
Refused to load the image 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRh4AAABXRUJQVlA4TBEAAAAvAQAAAAfQ//73v/+BiOh/AAA=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com".
```

Comment: Based on https://helmetjs.github.io/ there is no built-in support for worker-src. It also explicitly stated "This middleware performs very little validation. You should rely on CSP checkers like CSP Evaluator (https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) instead."

Answer (score 1):

Console warnings show that:

- You miss a **colon** in **blob:** scheme.
- You need to specify **data:** in the img-src directive.